# FileUtils.mv throwing Invalid char \302 and \255 exception

Tags: ruby

When I run the below code in `CodeRunner` or from the command line I get the following error;

```
Untitled.rb:25: Invalid char '\302' in expression
Untitled.rb:25: Invalid char '\255' in expression
```

Line 25 corresponds to the line with the `FileUtils.mv` method.

```
if the_file.include? "Screen Shot"
    old_file = Shellwords.escape(homepath + "/Desktop/" + the_file)
    new_file = Shellwords.escape(screen_shot_folder + "/" + the_file)

    FileUtils.­mv old_file, new_file
end
```

Initially I thought there was something wrong with my input (either `old_file` or `new_file`) which is why I have wrapped them in `Shellwords.escape` I have also checked that the contents of `old_file` and `new_file` are correct.

If I call `puts old_file + " ++ " + new_file` I get something like the following;

```
/Users/tobyosbourn/Desktop/Screen\ Shot\ 2013-02-04\ at\ 10.49.14\ \(2\).png ++ /Users/tobyosbourn/Desktop/Screenshots/Screen\ Shot\ 2013-02-04\ at\ 10.49.14\ \(2\).png
```

Which looks spot on but if I copy and paste those as strings into FileUtils.mv I get the same error message.

I have [read how FileUtils is meant to be used](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mv) and couldn't see anything I am doing wrong, could anyone advise?

If it helps my version of Ruby is `1.8.7`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an *invisible non-ASCII character* in your source code, likely added by copy-and-pasting code off a website somewhere.

To be specific, you've got a rogue soft-hyphen in your code, encoded as UTF-8 (soft-hyphen = C2 AD in UTF-8, or \302\255 in octal escape notation).

Best thing to do would be to "show invisibles" in your text editor and see if you can find a space that isn't like the others.

**EDIT** Pasting your snippet into my text editor reveals a soft-hyphen right after `FileUtils.` (between `.` and `mv`). Delete `FileUtils.mv` and retype it to get rid of the character if you can't see it.

Comment: I have show invisibles on and had a really good look and didn't spot that at all - it took me to move through the line one character at a time to see it. Thanks!

Comment: Some text editors won't show you this stuff. (My back up plan in these events is to hexdump my source code, which thankfully I've only had to do once in my career).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to get rid of invisible characters in copy-and-paste text is to copy it first to a primitive text editor such as Notepad in Windows or Nano in Linux, which automatically gets rid of most of the unwanted stuff, edit out remaining suspicious characters, and paste it from there. For instance, if I paste your FileUtils.mv into Notepad, I get FileUtils.¬mv