# Session variable in hidden field not being passed to $_POST on submit

Tags: php, forms

I've have this bit in my processor.php file...

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['field_2'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['field_1'];
```

Those variables are being passed to another page and pre-filling inputs on a  second form like this...

```html
<input type="hidden" name="Name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>">
<input name="Address" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['address']?>">
```

Then that form is being submitted to email...

```
mail($to, $subject,"Form data:
Name: " . $_POST['Name'] . "
Property Address: " . $_POST['Address'] . "
More Fields ", $headers
);
```

The email comes through successfully with the pre-filled "Property Address" but "Name" is blank.  Why is the hidden input not passing the variable for `$_POST['Name']`?

Comment: Has the session been started for all pages using sessions? Show us where you've assigned it for `$_SESSION['name']`.

Comment: Outputs `$_POST['field_1'];` with var_dump or debug() and see if there something inside it.

Comment: Just mark the input fileds as `type="text"` for debugging purposes and check the value displayed in the browser.

Comment: try to inspect your hidden input, I'll bet it get no value

Comment: You also shouldn't be abusing your mail headers like that. It just gives it room for errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @VolkerK & Bang;   I thought of that already, the value is definitely being echoed into the field. `<input type="hidden" name="Name" value="John">`

Comment: Sorry guys have to go to a meeting... "I will be back."

Comment: When the values are already in the form as string literals it's no longer a question about anything session related, is it?

Comment: Really hard to know if `$_POST['field_2']` is related to `$_POST['Address']`. I was tempted to put in an answer earlier, but have decided not to; not till I see full/more code and "actual" code.

Comment: @ Fred -ii-  I am not sure how I am abusing the mail headers. Can you explain

Comment: This is what I tried, when I switched the hidden field over to `type=text` and changed nothing else, the field was definitely being populated.  But the processing script was still not picking up the variable. I checked and double checked my code for syntax errors several times and found nothing. I did finally get it working, and am wondering how I should demonstrate that.  Just edit my question? or should I answer my own question?

Comment: You're injecting a whole bunch of stuff into headers. There are more efficient and streamlined methods to do this. Plus, in doing what you're doing now, leaves you open to XSS injection. Now, I need to see your actual code and more of it too. I can't answer without it.

Comment: This is what my headers contains `$headers = 'From: contactform@xyz.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: contactform@xyz.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();`  It is all only going to email not a database, so I don't need to really worry about XSS do I?

Comment: Sorry, I meant about `mail($to, $subject,"Form data:
Name: " . $_POST['Name'] . "
Property Address: " . $_POST['Address'] . "` You could simply predefine your variables, then concatenate them as one variable, then simply use the one in your message parameter. Now, is what you posted your real code? In regards to `$_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['field_2'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['field_1'];`? I've already asked this, but you didn't answer my question about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71225/discussion-between-skribe-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 0):

While it seemed like the hidden field was the problem, it was not. Every thing was working except for the second line here.

```
mail($to, $subject,"Form data:
Name: " . $_POST['Name'] . "
Email: " . $_POST['Email'] . "  
Property Address: " . $_POST['Address'] . "
Lots More Fields ", $headers);
```

The whole `mail()' function bit was a copy-and-paste snip-it from the web into Sublime Text. The syntax was perfect, but I eventually found that there was **an invisible non-ASCII character** in the Name line left over from the copy paste from web snip-it operation. I checked if anyone else ever had a similar problem like this and immediately found this [FileUtils.mv throwing Invalid char \302 and \255 exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863720/fileutils-mv-throwing-invalid-char-302-and-255-exception)

The moral of the story is that saving time by using snipits may not always save you time. I should have enabled `"draw_white_space"` in Sublime Text and I would have probably caught it a lot sooner.

**As Fred -ii- pointed out** the message body arguments all would have been better concatenated as a `$message` variable. Whose advice I've now followed.

Answer (score -1):

At step 2, check in the generated HTML code if the "value" attribute have the correct value.

Also, instead of using at step 3 **$_POST['Name']** , use **$_REQUEST['Name']**. With this, it will work if POST or GET request.

Comment: be the most restrictive as you can in order to secure your code.