# ESlint "Expected indentation of 1 tab character but found 0" error

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am getting aמ indentation error that I am having a hard time reasoning. Would really appreciate some help. Here's the stripped down Header.js file where ESlint thinks something is amiss:

```
import React from 'react';

function Header() {
  return <p>Test</p>;
}

module.exports = Header;
```

ESlint throws an error

```
4:3  error  Expected indentation of 1 tab character but found 0  indent
```

my .eslintrc file is as follows:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
   "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "arrow-body-style": [0],
    "comma-dangle": 0,
    "indent": [2, "tab", {"SwitchCase": 1}],
    "no-console": 0,
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-indent-props": [2, "tab"]
  }
}
```

ESLint version is 2.11.1

I am definitely missing something to get this error. But can't figure out what. I have looked into ESlint documentation; but my usage seems correct. I have checked the tab spacing on line 4 too.

Update 1:

The error disappeared when I typed out the same code in vim. I think the error has to do with some sublime settings/plugins that I installed recently.

Update 2:

Figured out the problem.

My sublime settings mentioned

```
"tab_size": 4,
```

That is incompatible with my .eslintrc file. I changed the settings to

```
"tab_size": 2,
```

and the issue was resolved.

Thanks a lot for all of you who commented

Comment: Are you using spaces instead of tab values before your `return` statement?

Comment: No, I am using tab. Checked multiple times. Even added additional tabs to get a different error. For example, if I add 2 more tabs to line 4, I get the following error "4:7  error  Expected indentation of 1 tab character but found 0  indent"

Comment: Also check for "hidden" unicode chars.

Comment: Is it possible that your editor is converting your tabs into spaces automatically?

Comment: Also, can you paste the actual character(s) used for indentation? In the example in your post, you are using two spaces on line 4.

Comment: No "hidden" characters. Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863720/fileutils-mv-throwing-invalid-char-302-and-255-exception as part of my research trying to debug the problem. As a test, I copied the code into Nano and pasted it back into the Header.js file. The error remains the same

Comment: I am using Sublime. Preferences are set to "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,

Comment: Not sure how to paste it in the Stackoverflow editor

Comment: There are a couple options: 1) Select and copy just the indentation character(s) from Sublime and then replace the two spaces in the SO editor with the copied text. 2) Temporarily change your Sublime indentation settings to "Indent using spaces" and "Tab width: 4" (View > Indentation > …), then select your entire code block in Sublime and press tab to indent it by 4 spaces. This should preserve your pre-existing tabs while giving you a block of code that can be copied into the SO editor with each line indented by 4 spaces to achieve the desired markdown formatting.

Comment: I think the error does have to do with how tabs/white spaces are being treated in Sublime. I wrote out the same code in Vim and the error disappeared.